# Serial over Bluetooth on Windows: how to get connection status

Tags: bluetooth, serial-port

Using a serial over bluetooth device (ESP32 in my case), the Windows driver shows the connection status in the bluetooth enumeration as show below.

[image: Serial Over Bluetooth]

How is it possible to have the same information programmatically, using .NET, without trying to open the corresponding COM port?

Comment: There is a way that Bluetooth Framework uses. You can check any Bluetooth device status (connected/disconnected) as well as disconnect any paired device. By its MAC.

Comment: Mike, thank you for your answer. From the DeviceInformation I can see the Paired/Unpaired status but (as far as I am concerned) not the COM connected/unconnected status.

Comment: Yes, thats correct. There is no WinRT API for reading connected/disconnected status. You should query Bluetooth driver directly.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I get the connection status using the InTheHand.Net.Sockets resource.

```
using InTheHand.Net.Sockets;

BluetoothClient btcli = new BluetoothClient();
IEnumerable<BluetoothDeviceInfo> dl = btcli.PairedDevices;
```

where the BluetoothDeviceInfo class contains the connected information.